# PyShark+Django : Unable to make async call when pyshark is used in a Django view

Tags: django, django-views, python-asyncio, wireshark, pyshark

I am using pyshark module in a Django view to get the ports breakdown from an uploaded PCAP file.

views.py

```
class ProtocolAnalysisView(APIView):
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser,)

    def analyze_pcap(self, pcap_file):
        res = {}
        capture = pyshark.FileCapture(
            pcap_file.temporary_file_path(), keep_packets=True)

        hl_dict = {}
        tl_dict = {}
        try:
            i = 0
            while True:
                hl = capture[i].highest_layer
                tl = capture[i].transport_layer
                if hl not in hl_dict:
                    hl_dict[hl] = 0
                if tl not in tl_dict:
                    tl_dict[tl] = 0
                hl_dict[hl] += 1
                tl_dict[tl] += 1
                i += 1
        except KeyError:
            capture.close()

        res["tcp_packet_counts"] = tl_dict.get("TCP", 0)
        res["udp_packet_counts"] = tl_dict.get("UDP", 0)
        res["transport_layer_breakdown"] = [
            {"transport_layer_protocol": key, "count": value} for key, value in tl_dict.items()
        ]
        res["protocol_breakdown"] = [
            {"highest_layer_protocol": key, "count": value} for key, value in hl_dict.items()
        ]
        return res

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = PcapFileSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            pcap_file = serializer.validated_data['pcap_file']
            res = self.analyze_pcap(pcap_file)
            return Response({"data": res}, status=200)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=400)
```

The serializer used here:

```
class PcapFileSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    pcap_file = serializers.FileField(
        allow_empty_file=False, allow_null=False, help_text="Upload a pcap file.")
```

When I POST the a using form-data, Django throws the below exception:
**Exception Value: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-1 (process_request_thread)'**.

Using library like scapy and dpkt is not an option for me. So I dig deep anf got to know that pyshark uses async call under the hood and django works in a synchronous manner.
I have tried to use async calls , but I was getting below errors:
*Expected a `Response`, `HttpResponse` or `HttpStreamingResponse` to be returned from the view, but received a `<class 'coroutine'>` *

Please suggest me an approach.